# Programatically reduce time interval in handler. Android

Tags: java, android, handler, timing

When you use the postDelayed function on a handler, a delayMillis variable is required to specify the time after which the handler runs. I want my handler to repeat indefinitely so I have nested two postDelayed functions.

```
    final int initialdt = 1000;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            handler.postDelayed(this, initialdt);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, initialdt);
```

However using this method, the time between the run() calls is fixed. Since the inner postDelayed requires a **final** integer as a parameter. I want to reduce the time between consecutive calls. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
    final int initialDt = 1000;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        int dt = initialDt;
        public void run() {
            dt -= 100;
            if (dt >= 0) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, dt);
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, initialDt);
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried declaring dt inside **run** and outiside the runnable, but it didnt occur to me to try inside the runnable and outside of run.

Comment: You're welcome. If you're happy with this solution, I would love that you assign me the correct answer check-mark. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

You could set the limit inside `postDelayed`

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                handler.postDelayed(this, limit);
            }
        }, 1000);
```